# Find all binary strings of certain weight has fast as possible

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, multiprocessing, python-itertools

I want to find binary strings of a certain weight. The amount of such strings grows to the point of a memory error, so I'm currently generating them with a generator. This code generators all length n binary strings with weight k:

```py
def kbits(n, k):
    for bits in itertools.combinations(range(n), k):
        s = ['0'] * n
        for bit in bits:
            s[bit] = '1'
        yield ''.join(s)

for b in kbits(length, weight):
    print(b)
```

So for length = 3 and weight = 2, we get 110, 101, 011.

My research requires me to parse through values such as n = 56 and k = 7, which takes around 24 hours on my device. I'd also like to try n = 72 and k = 8, which (based on the time of the previous result) may take 365 days. So I'm wondering two things:

1. Is this the quickest (non-memory) intensive way of generating these binary strings?
2. Is it possible to have multiple cores of my CPU working on this at once? I'm assuming itertools is parsing through a sequence. If (let's say) we had a 2-core CPU, would it be possible to have the first core parse the first 50% of the sequence and the second core to do the latter half?

EDIT:

Perhaps I should mention that for each boolean b, I'd like to perform the following least-squares computation, where N is some defined matrix:

```
for b in kbits(size, max_coclique):
    v = np.linalg.lstsq(N,np.array(list(b), dtype = float))
```

i.e. I require the ultimate expected output format for b to be a `numpy` array with 0/1 values. (That is unless there is some extremely fast way of doing all of this - including the least-squares computation - in a different way.)

Note: I'm also running this in Sage, as I am utilizing its database of transitive groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a value with weight *k*, you can get the lexically next value as follows:

1. Find the rightmost 0 to the left of the rightmost 1.
2. move a 1 from the right into that 0
3. move all the other 1s to the right of that zero as far right as possible.

This is the binary version of the Pandita algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order

You can do it with bit manipulations like this:

```
def kbits(n, k):
    limit=1<<n
    val=(1<<k)-1
    while val<limit:
        yield "{0:0{1}b}".format(val,n)
        minbit=val&-val #rightmost 1 bit
        fillbit = (val+minbit)&~val  #rightmost 0 to the left of that bit
        val = val+minbit | (fillbit//(minbit<<1))-1
```

There are probably some opportunities for optimization remaining, but the time will be dominated by formatting the values as binary strings in the `yield` statement.

Comment: This works remarkably fast! Any thoughts on how one could start the sequence at any point? (With the idea being to allocate a segment of each sequence to a different core.)

Comment: I don't have a fast way to do that, but you wouldn't need a fast way for that purpose.  There are C(n,k) permutations, so divide that number by the number of threads to get the start points and then binary search to get the position of each 1 in turn.  OR just generate a bunch of random start points.  If your threads take segments from a work queue when they're free, and you have, say 10 times as many segments as cores, then the work will even out all by itself.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Let's say n = 6 and k = 2. Then C(6, 2) = 15. Let's say we have two threads. So 15/2 = 7.5. Then say the first thread starts at 1 and the second thread starts at 8. But how do I call the function such that it starts at the 8th entry when `val` relies on the previous iteration? I tried looking for patterns between the value of `val` and the number of the sequence, but I can't seem to find one. I could always find the required `val` by running through the loop - is that the only way? Providing a short coded example with n=6 and k=2 would be very helpful!

Comment: The loop generates values in lexical order, which is the same as numeric order, so you just need to find the 8th one, and then run one thread from `(1<<k)-1` to the 8th value, and one from the 8th value to `(1<<k)-1`.  But which one is the 8th value?  Well, where does the first 1 go?  There are at C(3,2) = 3 that fit into the last 3 bits, so it doesn't go there.  There are at C(4,2) = 6 that fit into the last 4, so not there.  There are C(5,2) = 10 that fit into the last 5.  That's the smallest that includes the 8th value, so the first 1 is 5th from the end.  Continue for the other bits.

Comment: Conceptually I understand what you mean. I've battled this for a while and I'm not sure how to implement it. The 7th entry is 010001 for n = 6 and k = 2. The 8th is 010010. How can you start the above function so that the first 1 is 5th from the end, while not choosing the 7th entry?

Answer (score 0):

I would store the current number in an integer variable and then do binary bitwise operations (`&`, `^`, `|`) to move the bits. With recursion to smaller length and weight that can probably done with few lines of code.

Binary bitwise operations are presumably way faster than string operations, particularly if you do not need to print out every number.

Comment: Well for each b I'll be solving a matrix-vector equation Nv = b (where N is some defined matrix): `v = np.linalg.lstsq(N,np.array(list(b), dtype = float))`. Would I be able to do this if b is not a string? Could you provide a coded little example of what you mean?

Comment: @DanP. If the ultimate expected output format is a `numpy` array with 0/1 values, it should be explicitly mentioned in the post. The `numpy` tag might also be added.

Answer (score 0):

An extremely fast method for generating the lexographically next bit permutation is available at https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation .  Since it uses compiler intrinsics, you may have to compile this in C and then use Python's C interface to actually operate it.  If you start with the k least significant bits set to 1 and the rest set to 0, you should be able to use this operation to permute through the whole set.

Since this operation (mostly) approximates an iterator, you should be able to parallelize by breaking the problem into ranges that you could have multiple threads iterate against.

To convert the integers back to a string, you can do a loop of checking the first bit (easily achieved by doing bitwise AND against 1) and prepending to a string a '0' if it's 0 or '1' if it's 1, then doing a rightward shift.  If you do this for the length of the bit string, you will have converted the integer to a string.

Comment: There is another version below that does not need the compiler intrinsics.