# Multiprocessing a Straight-forward Computation

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, multiprocessing, sage

Breakdown of the problem: There's a fair bit of underlying motivation, but let's say we are given some matrix `N` (code included at the bottom) and we wish to solve the matrix-vector equation `Nv = b`, where `b` is a binary string of weight `k`. I'm currently solving this using `numpy.linalg.lstsq`. If the 'residual' of this least-square calculation is less than 0.000001, I'm accepting it as a solution.

First, I need to generate all binary strings of a certain `length` and `weight k`. The following function does this.

```
'''
This was provided in one of the answers here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58069431/find-all-binary-strings-of-certain-weight-has-fast-as-possible/
Given a value with weight k, you can get the (co)lexically next value as follows (using bit manipulations).
'''
def ksubsetcolexsuccessor(length,k):
    limit=1<<length
    val=(1<<k)-1
    while val<limit:
        yield "{0:0{1}b}".format(val,length)
        minbit=val&-val
        fillbit = (val+minbit)&~int(val)
        val = val+minbit | (fillbit//(minbit<<1))-1
```

So for `length = 6` and `k = 2` we have: 
0

```
00011, 000101, 000110, 001001, 001010, 001100, 010001, 010010, 010100, 011000, 100001, 100010, 100100, 101000, 110000.
```

We plug each into `Nv = b` and solve:

```
import numpy as np

solutions = 0
for b in ksubsetcolexsuccessor(n, k):
    v = np.linalg.lstsq(N,np.array(list(b), dtype = float)) 
    if v[1] < 0.000001:
        solutions += 1
```

This totals the amount of solutions. My issue is that this is fairly slow. I'd like to eventually try `n = 72` and `k = 8`. I noticed that only a fraction of my CPU is being used, so I'd like to multiprocess. I started by figuring out how to generate the above binary strings in chunks. I have written a function which gives me values for `val` that allows me to start and stop generating the above binary string sequence in any place. So my plan was to have as many chunks as I have cores on my machine. For example:

Core 1 processes: `000011, 000101, 000110, 001001, 001010, 001100, 010001`

Core 2 processes: `010010, 010100, 011000, 100001, 100010, 100100, 101000, 110000`

I am unfamiliar with `multiprocessing` and `multithreading`. Here is what I've done:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

'''
A version where you can specify where to start and end by passing start_val and end_val to the function.
It performs the least-squares computation for each b and tallies the trials that work.
'''
def ksubsetcolexsuccessorSegmentComp(n, k, val, limit, num):
    while val<limit:
        b = "{0:0{1}b}".format(val,n)
        v = np.linalg.lstsq(N,np.array(list(b), dtype = float))
        if v[1] < 0.000001:
            num += 1

        minbit=val&-val
        fillbit = (val+minbit)&~int(val)
        val = val+minbit | (fillbit//(minbit<<1))-1

    print(num)


solutions = 0
length = 6
weight = 2
start_val = (1<<k)-1
mid_val = 18 #If splitting into 2 processes
end_val = 1<<n

#Multiprocessing
p1 = Process(target=ksubsetcolexsuccessorSegmentComp, args=(length, weight, start_val, mid_val, solutions))
p2 = Process(target=ksubsetcolexsuccessorSegmentComp, args=(length, weight, mid_val, end_val, solutions))

p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()
```

This does indeed reduce the computation time by around 45% (with increasing the length and weight). My CPU runs at around 50% during this. Oddly enough, if I split into 4 processes it takes roughly the same as if I split into 2 (even though my CPU runs at around 85% during that). On the laptop I'm testing this on, I have 2 physical cores and 4 logical cores. How many processes is optimal on such a CPU?

Questions:

1. In my lack of knowledge of multiprocessing, have I done this correctly? i.e. is this the fastest way to multiprocess this program?
2. Can anyone see any clear way to improve computation time? I've looked into multithreading within each process, but it seemed to slow down the computation.
3. The slowest part of this is definitely `np.linalg.lsts`q. Are there any clever ways to speed this part up?

If anyone wishes to test the code, here is how I generate the matrix `N`:

```
'''
Creating the matrix N
'''
def matrixgenerator(G, cardinality, degree):
    matrix = np.zeros((size, (n-1)**2 + 1))
    #Generate the matrix (it'll be missing stab_nn)
    column_index = 0
    for i in range(1,n):
        for j in range(1,n):
            for k in range(size):
                if G[k](i) == j:
                    matrix[k][column_index] = 1
            column_index += 1

    #Determine the final column of N, which is determined by the characteristic vector of stab_nn
    for k in range(size):
        if G[k](n) == n:
            matrix[k][(n-1)**2] = 1

    return matrix

n = 3 #This will give length 6 and weight 2 binary strings
#Try n = 7 and change the second argument below to '4' - this takes roughly 14 min with 2 processes on my device
Group = TransitiveGroup(n, 2) #SageMath 8.8
length = Group.order()
weight = int(size / n)

N = matrixgenerator(Group, length, n)
```

This requires SageMath 8.8. Note this is the only part of the code that requires SageMath. Everything else is effectively written in Python 2.7. Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Speaking The Performance** - what are the acceptable levels ***of the** ( expected ) **fastest way among all the as-fast-as-possible approaches?*** Having no quantitative targets, any path may lead one forwards.

Comment: Well I suppose if you see anything that can be improved it’d be great if you could explain what that is and I’ll make the change. My quantitative target is that i don’t want n=168 and k=21 to take 6 months to compute I guess.

Comment: If my faint recollection of linear algebra is correct then you needn't solve so many eqns. Just solve for the  standard base, e1,e2,e3,... project back to get ehat1,ehat2,ehat3,... and now look for groups j1,j2,j3 (the positions of the ones in your binary words) of your desired size that satisfy e_j1+e_j2+e_j3+... approx ehat_j1+ehat_j2+ehat_j3+... You should be able to get all the ehats in one go as the columns of `N@np.linalg.pinv(N)`

Comment: But however well you optimize, looping through all 168-choose-21 (~2.9 x 10^26) words is not feasible.

Comment: The matrix N is in fact already the collection of basis vectors but I’ll think about what you said carefully. Perhaps I was a little zealous. What about n = 72 and k = 8?

Comment: 72-choose-8 may just about be doable at 11969016345 binary words. You can compute those values yourself, for example this one I got using `scipy.special.comb(72,8,exact=True)`. Btw. by standard basis I mean (1,0,0,...) (0,1,0,...) (0,0,1,...) etc., in your terminology that would be binary strings of length n and weight 1. Also, if N is a basis, why do you expect any of the Nv=b to be not exactly solvable?

Comment: Yes I often compute using `scipy.special.comb` but what's the cut-off point for being "doable"? Is there actually a number where this becomes non-feasible? Also recall that b is a certain weight. Not all such b's yield an exact solution. For example, for the symmetric group of order 3 (TransitiveGroup(3,2) above) there are only 9 boolean vectors of weight 2 that yield exact solutions (out of the 15 total weight 2 vectors).

Comment: Well, that seems to indicate to me that N is not in fact a basis.